# Smooth decay of smoke simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation, force-fields

I am trying to make a dust simulation. The kind of dust that appears when you knock out the dust from the carpet.

[image]

I use geometry as flow behavior.

[image]

cylinder as effector and wind. But my "dust" disappears instantly and doesn't feel like dust at all.

[image]

I expect that when the dust spreads to some distance, a cavity will form in the center and the dust itself will disappear more slowly.

[image]

Help me improve my animation please.

[image] (Blender v 3.3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Wind pressures in the scene in constant axe direction and doesn't let smoke to roll.
You need only central (point) force.

Try to limit Wind – *Falloff > Radial > Max Distance* ...

[image]

Notes:

- I'm not sure if 50 frames in Cache is enough to take effect.
- For Domain set a bit of Vorticity.
- Smoke appearance is set in Smoke > Properties > Viewport ...

[image]

Comment: Looks great, can you upload the blend-file?

Comment: Sure ... updated