# why does smoke simulation in solid view look better than rendered?

Tags: smoke-simulation

i'm styding smoke from this this post's file [Smooth decay of smoke simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275739/smooth-decay-of-smoke-simulation/275745)
and i'm wondering why does smoke simulation in solid view look better than rendered? i mean it's more stylized, but that's exactly what i'm looking for!
[image]
is there any way to achieve similar to solid view result in render? i know that in solid view the domain uses grid display option so i think i have to look up somewhere in shader of the domain. am i right?

Comment: Have you set up a material for volume?

Comment: @Crantisz as i can see it is set up by default for the domain - principled volume shader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks as if on the left side, towards be border of the smoke where it gets thinner, i.e. the density goes towards 0, it turns to black.

I cannot exactly reproduce it, but a similar effect can be achieved if you plug the *Density* output of the *Volume Info* node into the *Color* ot the *Principled Volume* and use a *Color Ramp* inbetween where you move the black slider from the left in to color the less dense borders with black.

In my example I also made it a bit pinkish red as it it seems in your example, maybe you can even use the density info for some emission. My answer is more a general idea of what you can do to get more stylized smoke, not a finished replica of the reference. It's all a matter of playing around with the settings to get it right. Or to get it somehow as you like it.

[image: stylized smoke]

As asked in the comments: this works in *Eevee* as well, but most likely you have to adjust the *Volumetrics* settings, because volumetrics do not work to well out-of-the-box like in *Cycles*. The settings shown here are just for my specific scene (especially the *Start/End* values), you might need them to be different:

[image: stylized smoke eevee]

Comment: man that's awesome! thanks a lot. btw is it working only in cycles?

Comment: @EvgeniyPupkin You're welcome! No, it's working in _Eevee_ as well, but as other things it might not exactly look like in _Cycles_ but basically it's the same. I've edited my answer for an _Eevee_ example. If this helped you, you might consider accepting the answer.

Comment: thank you, i really appreciate it!